# Js page is not loading in chrome when I am invoking from automation

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-chromedriver

When any JS page is coming Chrome drover is throwing the  below error in console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

```js
private WebDriver getChromeDriver() throws IOException {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    ChromeDriverService service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
            .usingDriverExecutable(new File("./src/main/resources/driver/chromedriver.exe")).usingAnyFreePort().build();
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();        
    options.merge(capabilities);
    options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");        
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
    return driver;
}
```

Do I need to add any option in chrome driver?

Comment: That error usually shows up when jquery library is not declared in a web page

Answer (score 0):

This is due to security feature that chrome browser implement, that is chrome do not allow to load external files locally. This can be changed upto some extent from the 'setting' option.

Comment: Can you please let  me know which option do I need to set?